# Removing redundant rows in a Spark data frame with time series data

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark data frame that looks like this (simplifying timestamp and id column values for clarity):

```
| Timestamp | id |     status  |
--------------------------------
|         1 |  1 |     pending |
|         2 |  2 |     pending |
|         3 |  1 | in-progress |
|         4 |  1 | in-progress |
|         5 |  3 | in-progress |
|         6 |  1 |     pending |
|         7 |  4 |      closed |
|         8 |  1 |     pending |
|         9 |  1 | in-progress |
```

It's a time series of status events. What I'd like to end up with is only the rows representing a status change. In that sense, the problem can be seen as one of removing redundant rows - e.g. entries at times 4 and 8 - both for id = 1 - should be dropped as they do not represent a change of status for a given id.

For the above set of rows, this would give (order being unimportant):

```
| Timestamp | id |     status  |
--------------------------------
|         1 |  1 |     pending |
|         2 |  2 |     pending |
|         3 |  1 | in-progress |
|         5 |  3 | in-progress |
|         6 |  1 |     pending |
|         7 |  4 |      closed |
|         9 |  1 | in-progress |
```

Original plan was to partition by id and status, order by timestamp, and pick the first row for each partition - however this would give

```
| Timestamp | id |     status  |
--------------------------------
|         1 |  1 |     pending |
|         2 |  2 |     pending |
|         3 |  1 | in-progress |
|         5 |  3 | in-progress |
|         7 |  4 |      closed |
```

i.e. it loses repeated status changes.

Any pointers appreciated, I'm new to data frames and may be missing a trick or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `lag` window function should do the trick

```
case class Event(timestamp: Int, id: Int, status: String)

val events = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    Event(1, 1, "pending") :: Event(2, 2, "pending") ::
    Event(3, 1, "in-progress") :: Event(4, 1, "in-progress") ::
    Event(5, 3, "in-progress") :: Event(6, 1, "pending") ::
    Event(7, 4, "closed") :: Event(8, 1, "pending") ::
    Event(9, 1, "in-progress") :: Nil
))

events.registerTempTable("events")

val query = """SELECT timestamp, id, status FROM (
    SELECT timestamp, id, status, lag(status) OVER (
        PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp
    ) AS prev_status  FROM events) tmp
    WHERE prev_status IS NULL OR prev_status != status
    ORDER BY timestamp, id"""

sqlContext.sql(query).show
```

Inner query

```
SELECT timestamp, id, status, lag(status) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp
) AS prev_status  FROM events
```

creates table as below where `prev_status` is a previous value of `status` for a given `id` and ordered by `timestamp`.

```
+---------+--+-----------+-----------+
|timestamp|id|     status|prev_status|
+---------+--+-----------+-----------+
|        1| 1|    pending|       null|
|        3| 1|in-progress|    pending|
|        4| 1|in-progress|in-progress|
|        6| 1|    pending|in-progress|
|        8| 1|    pending|    pending|
|        9| 1|in-progress|    pending|
|        2| 2|    pending|       null|
|        5| 3|in-progress|       null|
|        7| 4|     closed|       null|
+---------+--+-----------+-----------+
```

Outer query

```
SELECT timestamp, id, status FROM (...)
WHERE prev_status IS NULL OR prev_status != status
ORDER BY timestamp, id
```

simply filters rows where `prev_status` is `NULL` (first row for a given `id`) or `prev_status` is different than `status` (there was a status change between consecutive timestamps). Order added just to make a visual inspection easier.